# Converting .txt files into .xht on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, conversion, xhtml

I have a large sum of e-books that I need to have converted into .xht format. It's apparently pretty difficult to do judging from the lack of information on the internet. Or maybe it's just a really obscure conversion.

Either way, it would be great if anyone could help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look into the [txt2html Perl script](http://txt2html.sourceforge.net/).  There is a --xhtml argument you can pass to output XHTML instead of HTML.

I don't see any arguments in [the documentation](http://txt2html.sourceforge.net/txt2html.html) specifically for converting a whole directory of files, so you may need to write a small script that loops through each file in your directory, then calls txt2html on it.